# How to avoid possible memory leak at flushing an array stored in Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, flush

I'm playing with mail sending logic and the following code works as expected: for every recipient it builds an email content and sends it to a person:

```js
recipients.forEach((recipient) => {

    orders.forEach((order) => {
        if (order.ownerID === recipient.userID) {
            emailContent.blocks.push({
                content: "%EMAIL_TEXT%"
            });
        }
    });

    promises.push(mailer.sendEmail(recipient, emailContent));
    emailContent.blocks = [];
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

The only questionable moment is they way I flush the array before I start building a new email:

```js
emailContent.blocks = [];
```

I send the original content of `emailContent.blocks` to `mailer.sendEmail()` by storing it in promises array and then assign a new array to `emailContent.blocks`. Which might *theoretically* lead to the memory leak.

Do I need extra care about abandoned `emailContent.blocks` in this case? Or after finishing `await Promise.all(promises);` and exiting from a function garbage collector will do the job?

I just want to be sure that this code doesn't generate a memory leak.

Comment: _"I just want to be sure that this code doesn't generate a memory leak"_ - A profiler will tell you exactly that. If you haven't done this yet, there's no real reason to think about a _"possible memory leak"_.

Comment: Generally once there is no pointer to the object garbage collection takes care of it no? I guess there is the question of how mailer.sendEmail handles the emailContent

Comment: «How mailer.sendEmail handles the emailContent» — it compiles the email template with Handlebar and sends it to the gateway, quite plain, there I don't expect any trouble, but will check it with profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks very much like something the garbage collector will clean up.
I would be more worried about changing `emailContent.blocks` after you just sent `emailContent` to `mailer.sendMail`.

Since `emailContent` is sent by reference, settings `emailContent.blocks = []` will alter the value in `mailer.sendMail`.

It might work now but if `sendMail` ever becomes asynchronous (or just slower) then you'll have some really hard to solve bugs on your hand.

Not exactly sure what lies behind the `emailContent` variable but I'd suggest making a new `emailContent` variable every loop if possible.

And as Andreas suggested, use a profiler when in doubt.

Comment: As far as I understand, `emailContent.blocks = []` leaves the original content of `emailContent.blocks` as is, abandoned (actually creates a brand new (empty) array) and therefore no change could be applied to it later and `mailer.sendMail` will always have a content I send to it before `emailContent.blocks = []`. Isn't?

Comment: @MikeB. `.blocks` stores a reference to an array. `.blocks = []` stores a reference to another array. After that line everybody that works with `.blocks` only "sees" the new array.

Comment: "if `sendMail` ever becomes asynchronous (or just slower)" btw, it is already asynchronous   due to `await Promise.all(promises);`. or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Andreas, I've tried to spoof the values of `emailContent.blocks` after execution of `emailContent.blocks = []` and the original values have been preserved, so no side effect due to `= []` has been detected.

Comment: @MikeB. have a look at this pen as an example. Simplified version of your code showing the danger. https://codepen.io/invacto/pen/oNWXaJV?editors=1011

Comment: @Ian, thanks a lot for your sample! As far as I understand, the reason why I don't experience such issue is that V8 has not enough time to update the references that's why `sendEmail()` in my case still has proper values. Am I right?

Comment: @MikeB. Hard to say without seeing the code but probably. It could happen that future you decides to add some code to sendEmail in the future and all of a sudden nothing works anymore. That's what we call race conditions ;)